# Possible to use get_absolute_url in {% url %} tags without the model object?

Tags: django

I have a navbar where user can log in and after logging in, the user will have a dropdown menu with a link to his/her profile. Here are my codes:

**navbar.html:**

```
{% url 'students:student_profile_view' as student_profile_url %}

{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}

              <!-- User Dropdown Menu -->
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

                        <i class="far fa fa-user"></i> {{request.user.first_name}}</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ student_profile_url }}">Profile</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ logout_url }}">Logout</a>
                        </div>
                </li>
```

**students/urls.py:**

```
path('profile/<slug:slug>/', views.student_profile_view, name='student_profile_view'),
```

**students/model.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.text import slugify

class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='student_profile/', null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user)
        super(StudentProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        # return 'students:student_profile_view', (), {'slug': self.slug}
        return reverse("students:student_profile_view", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

Navbar.html is a base template, it's not being rendered through a view where I could've passed an object and then called `object.get_absolute_url` Right now the profile button in my navbar dropdown menu is not working as it's not finding a reverse match for the user.

Also, after logging in I tried entering the link to profile manually in my browser like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/students/profile/jimhalpert/`
I get an error saying ***Reverse for 'student_profile_view' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['students/profile/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']*** I assure you, the slug is correct.

Is there any way I can use `get_absolute_url` in navbar.html? why is hard coding the link in the browser not working? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all a bit confused.

The error presumably comes from the first line of that template, where you are attempting to reverse the `students:student_profile_view` URL without a slug. Clearly, that URL requires a slug, so you need to pass one when you reverse it. (I don't understand why you say that the slug is correct; you're not passing one at all.)

You appear to want to link to the profile of the current user; so you *do* have an object, namely `request.user.studentprofile`. So I don't understand why you don't just use that in the first place:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'students:student_profile_view' slug=request.user.studentprofile.slug %}">Profile</a>
```

or, since you have defined a `get_absolute_url` method that you're not using, you could use that:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ request.user.studentprofile.get_absolute_url }}">Profile</a>
```

Either way, you should remove that first line that is causing the problem.

Comment: I’m sorry I should’ve been more clear. I recently added a slug and an absolute url to my student profile. Before that the regular student profile url (without the slug) was working fine. I think your second solution will work. Thanks for the explanation.